# Go: factory returning pointer and interface{} type

Tags: interface, go, factory

Consider the following factory: [Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/AUyBFoqaW3)

```
type TypeA struct {
    placeholder int
}

func NewTypeA() *TypeA {
    return new(TypeA)
}

func main() {
  factory := make(map[string]func() interface{})
  factory["TypeA"] = NewTypeA
}
```

This gives me the following error: `cannot use NewTypeA (type func() *TypeA) as type func() interface {} in assignment` which is pretty clear.

I thought that `interface{}` was able to be matched with a pointer.

I found this solution: [Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/k7hJew9lvn)

```
type Entity interface {}

type TypeA struct {
    Entity
    placeholder int
}

func NewTypeA() Entity {
    return new(TypeA)
}

func main() {
  var tmp interface{}
  factory := make(map[string]func() Entity)
  factory["TypeA"] = NewTypeA
  tmp = factory["TypeA"]()
  log.Println(reflect.TypeOf(tmp))
}
```

Which gives me the expected type `*TypeA`.
Is there an other way to do this using the `interface{}` type directly instead of a "dumb" interface (`Entity`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 2nd example `NewTypeA()` returns `Entity` not `*TypeA`, so it is no different from a solution where `NewTypeA()` would return `interface{}` which renders the `Entity` type completely needless/redundant:

```
type TypeA struct {
    placeholder int
}

func NewTypeA() interface{} {
    return new(TypeA)
}

func main() {
    factory := make(map[string]func() interface{})
    factory["TypeA"] = NewTypeA

    tmp := factory["TypeA"]()
    fmt.Printf("%T", tmp)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/77E92GDnv5)):

```
*main.TypeA
```

#### Keeping the `*TypeA` return type

For convenience if you want your `NewTypeA()` factory function to still return `*TypeA`, you can do so by putting an anonymous wrapper function in your `factory` map:

```
func NewTypeA() *TypeA {
    return new(TypeA)
}

func main() {
    factory := make(map[string]func() interface{})
    factory["TypeA"] = func() interface{} { return NewTypeA() }

    tmp := factory["TypeA"]()
    fmt.Printf("%T", tmp)
}
```

Output again ([Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/vUrCaJeXlw)):

```
*main.TypeA
```

Comment: Of course! Why didn't I think of that? Thank you! I didn't know the `%T` flag by the way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you fully understand what an interface{} is and thus are trying to use it incorrectly.

As stated in [this article](http://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go):

> The interface{} type, the empty interface, is the source of much
>   confusion.

I'd recommend that you read that article and then have another look at what you are trying to do.

An interface{} is not a placeholder for any other type, it's a [type itself](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types).

So if you create a map that takes functions that return interface{} as keys then that's the type the functions needs to return. Not a pointer or int or anything else.

While you can assign a value of any type to an interface, including pointer types, you can't use other types in place of an interface{} type.

It seems that what you are trying to accomplish is have a map with functions that can return a value of any type. You can only do that indirectly by designing your functions differently. You'd have to use an interface{} type in the function, assign the value you want to return to it and then return the interface{}. But you have to return type interface{} and not type int or string or *TypeA or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for the article! I red it when I started to use go couple months ago. This is still not entirely clear to me, I'll read it again.